# PHP Smarty - anyway to remove html outputted from include file?

Tags: php, smarty

including a file in a template but its showing on frontend with the html as well, ive tried to unescape but no joys, anyone have any ideas?

```
{include file="buttons/add_to_cart_filling.tpl" but_id="button_cart_`$obj_prefix``$obj_id`" but_name="dispatch[checkout.add..`$obj_id`]" but_role=$but_role block_width=$block_width obj_id=$obj_id product=$product but_meta=$add_to_cart_meta but_text="Buy Now with `$filling_total`lt filling (+$`$filling_total_cost|unescape:"html"`) "}

> Buy Now with 450lt filling (+$<span class="ty-list-price
> ty-nowrap">$</span><span class="ty-list-price
> ty-nowrap">128.00</span>)
```

Comment: using unescape just shows the HTML as above, without and normal output decodes the tags into ASCII markup..... not sure how to sort this one....

Comment: You want the HTML code tags to be interpreted as HTML instead of text?